# Locate "LEV" in the String

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to make a validaiton if "LEV" exist. The "V" is the last letter in a string.

I'm looking for a regex that matches like this:

```
WATER LEV
answer: true

TTM DAB LEV
answer: true

FOODS IN2 LEV
answer: true

RLA LEV
answer: true

dd LEVFF
answer: false

RLA LEV 
answer: false due to white space after "V"
```

---

This is what I tried, but didn't work:

```
 LE*\D[V]
```

Comment: So, `LE` can be anywhere, and `V` is at the end? [`LE.*V$`](https://regex101.com/r/aI1wF8/1)? Your `*\D`  in the pattern is rather misleading.

Comment: Why not just `yourString.EndsWith("LEV");`?  Regular expressions seem like over kill for this.

Comment: Not a very clear question, but I guess `LE*\D[V]` is your attempt. This however implies that `E` can be repeated and that there **must** be another character - non digit - between the last `E` and the `V`. Which is it? To match what your describing `LEV\s*$` should do the trick.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew- In this context, only the the word "LEV" and not LE...V

Comment: juharr-never tried "EndsWith" before.

Comment: @KLN: If you want to check if `LEV` is at the very end, not followed with any whitespace, you can use `\bLEV\z`, or just use `String.EndsWith()`. Note that EndsWith won't check if `LEV` is a whole word or not, while `\b` will ensure it is a whole word.

Comment: @ClasG That would match trailing spaces, which the OP does not want _false due to white space after "V"_

Comment: Should it match a string like "STUFFLEV".  Or does "LEV" need to be preceeded by a space?  And in that case would it still need to match just "LEV"?

Comment: @juharr As I said - not a very clear question. I interpret it as that begin the problem - that it **should** return true. But, I'm not sure.

Comment: @juharr *The "V" is the last **letter** in a string.*

Comment: @ClasG OK I see how you interrupted that.  I though the OP was explaining why that case was suppose to be false since it's not obvious that the string has a space at the end.

Comment: @KLN: Did you want to allow any number of non-digit characters between `LE` and `D`? The `LE\D*[V]` matches `LERTESDFGR%^&*&^%V` anywhere inside a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
LEV$
```

The `$` at the end means `end of string`.

If you want to match whole word `LEV` at the end of string, prefix it with a `\b` which means `word boundary`

```
\bLEV$
```

Comment: This won't handle the trailing white space. Use `LEV\s*$`.

Comment: He doesn't want trailing spaces. See the last one in his list of examples.

Comment: *The "V" is the last **letter** in a string.* Se my comment above.

Comment: Yes, `$` means the end of string, but not the *very end* of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Huh...?

Comment: @ClasG: http://ideone.com/EGAxS3. **This answer - `LEV$` - does not mean that the `LEV` will be at the very end of the string.** Also, just using `LEV$` regex is inefficient in .NET. There is a way to greatly enhance matching at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That's correct when it comes to `newline`. In this case we're talking any `white space` though, and then your reasoning fails. I'm however still not clear on what OP wants - the description of the problem doesn't match the attempted RE... Writing this I notice this answer has been accepted though, so I guess - Now I know ;)

Comment: @KLN: You are aware you are not matching `LEV` at the end of the string with `\bLEV$`, aren't you? Also, you should use the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` - see my answer why.

Answer (score 1):

Let me clarify why `\bLEV$` is not a good answer.

The `$` anchor matches the end of the string, or the location before the last `\n` in the string that is its last character.  See [*Anchors* reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2):

> `$` - The match must occur at the end of the string **or before `\n` at the end of the line or string**.

Thus, **to match the very end of the string, you must use `\z` anchor**.

Next point is that the match should occur at the end of the string, but the regex engine is searching for a match from left to right by default. To greatly enhance matching, just use the `RegexOptions.RightToLeft` modifier to reverse the string analysis.

Thus, use

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\bLEV\z", RegexOptions.RightToLeft);
```

to find a whole word `LEV` at the very end of the string in an efficient way.

However, in most cases *when you do not need to check if the substring is a whole word* you can just use `String.EndsWith()`:

```
if (s.EndsWith("LEV")) {...}
```

Also, note that your `LE*\D[V]` matches:

- `L` - a literal `L` anywhere in the string followed with...
- `E*` - 0+ `E` characters followed with
- `\D` - a non-digit character (required!) followed with
- `[V]` - a `V` character.

Thus, `L^V` is a valid match acc. to this pattern.

Comment: By default, in C#, without changing options, `$` just matches the end of the string, not a new line. See [*Regular Expression Options*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd1hzczs(v=vs.110).aspx) reference.

Comment: @Rawling, you are wrong, see http://ideone.com/EGAxS3. If you do not believe me or the official reference, see the demo. **I am not thinking anything up**. `Regex.IsMatch("Some LEV\n", "LEV$");` will return `true`.

Comment: It is actually a very weird thing that has its roots in Perl regex. I do not know why they decided that .NET flavor  should inherit this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me. This is going to annoy me now :D