# Regular expression for any characters without spaces

Tags: c#, regex

What is the regular expression for all characters except white space , and minimum6 characters.

This is what I have now :

> ^[\w'?@&#.]{6,}$

But this does not accept all the special characters. And I am using in .net app if that makes any difference

Comment: Do you want just a space: `[^ ]` or do you want all whitespace characters: `\S` or `[^\s]`?

Comment: @Khauri McClain Want to ignore all white spaces

Comment: so should only alphanumeric and special characters

Comment: try `([^\s+]){6,}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[^\s]{6,}$` should make it. But note the answer above, if you only want to skip the **white spaces**, you better use `[^ ]`. The notation `[^\s]` will ignore any white space character (space, tab or newline).

Comment: Try not to include comments like 'note the answer above' in your answer, as yours is the only answer to this question that statement is misleading. Make your answers complete, certainly reference any user who's content you are borrowing but your answer will provide much more value if and get more votes if it is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

A .NET regex to match any string that does not contain *any* whitespace chars (at least 6 occurrences) is

```
\A\S{6,}\z
```

See the [regex demo online](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5CA%5CS%7B6%2C%7D%5Cz&i=1234a%3BA-%2B_.)

Do not use `$` because [it may match before a final `\n` (LF symbol) inside a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35916961/locate-lev-in-the-string/35917508#35917508), `\z` is the most appropriate anchor here as it matches the *very end* of the string. To make the string compatible with JS (if you use it in ASP.NET for both server and client side validation) you need to use `^\S{6,}$(?!\n)`.

The `\S` [shorthand character class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#NonWhitespaceCharacter) matches any character other than a Unicode whitespace  char (if ECMAScript option is not used).

The `{6,}` [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit) matches six or more occurrences of the quantified subpattern.

**Details**

- `\A` - (an unambiguous anchor, its behavior cannot be redefined with any regex options) start of a string
- `\S{6,}` - any 6 or more chars other than a Unicode whitespace char
- `\z` - the very end of the string.